# How to change TexStudio fonts for non-English

Tags: fonts, texstudio, editors

I have a problem with TexStudio fonts! I use it for writing Latex in Persian.
To make the environment suitable for typing, I tried to change the Editor font via

```
Options > Configure TexStudio > Editor > Font Family
```

And change it to a Persian font, but it just affects English scripts and not the Persian scripts!

How can I resolve this?!

Comment: @Davïd Thank, my problem is not with the `tex` but with the Editor! I have reported it to TexStudio Developers, it seems it doesn't support changing complex script fonts (as Persian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the font in this way doesn't instantly affect the Persian script. After that, you need to close the TexStudio and reopen it so that the changes are applied on Persian!